# Shell script elif

Tags: shell

I am new in shell script, trying to catch the return value of a program, and do something with it.

I have this script below

```
#!/bin/sh


if [ $# !=2 ] ; then
        echo "Usage : param1 param2 "
        exit 1;
elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
        ./callprogram
        $out = $?
        echo "$out"
fi

if [ $out==0 ]; then
    echo "out ok"
fi
```

It keeps getting me error of

```
"[: 11: 0: unexpected operator

out ok
```

I have no clue why line 11 is wrong. if I remove "fi", it will promt that it needs "fi". Can anyone help with this matter?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a space after the `[` and you need to use `-eq` (equals) or `-ne` (not equals) to compare numbers in your if-statement.

To assign a variable use `out=$?`, not `$out = $?`. There should be no spaces on either side of the `=` sign.

Try this:

```
if [ $# -ne 2 ] ; then
        echo "Usage : param1 param2 "
        exit 1
elif [ $# -eq 2 ]; then
        ./callprogram
        out=$?
        echo "$out"
fi

if [ $out -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "out ok"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
if [ $out==0 ]; then
```

to:

```
if [ $out = 0 ]; then
```

add spaces, and change '==' to '='. Note, that bash, executed as a bash accepts `==`. But if you run is as a sh it will say *"unexpected operator"*.

**Why:**

The `[` is a command (or symlink to test binary, depending on your OS and shell). It expects `$out` and `==` and `0` and `]` to be separate command arguments. If you miss the space around them, you have one argument `$out==0`.

**BTW:**

It's safer to always enquote the variables like that:

```
if [ "$var" ......
```

instead of

```
if [ $var
```

because when variable is empty, then you can get another error because of wrong number of arguments (no argument instead of empty string).

Comment: it returns me : "[: 11: 0: unexpected operator
[: 15: ==: unexpected operator
"

Comment: One argument that is not empty evaluates to 'true'.

Comment: @heike: sure, the correct argument is `=` not `==`. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: That is correct. The `[ $out==0 ]` will be semantically incorrect because it will be always true.

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems.  The one that is giving you the error is that you need a space after != on

```
if [ $# != 2 ]
```

(although `-ne` would be better than `!=`).  It appears that you are calling the script with 11 arguments, and then calling [ with the arguments 11 `!=2`, and it does not know what to do with !=2 because you meant `!= 2` but forgot the space.  Also, you want

```
out=$?
```

on the assignment (no $ on the LHS)
and

```
if [ $out = 0 ]
```

on the comparison.  (Spaces around the operator, which is '=' instead of '=='.  '==' will work on many shells, but '=' works in more shells.)

But your script would be better written without the explicit reference to $?

```
#!/bin/sh

if test $# != 2; then
        echo "Usage: $0 param1 param2 " >&2  # Errors go to stderr, not stdout
        exit 1;
fi
# you know $# is 2 here. No need to check

if ./callprogram; then
        echo "out ok"
fi
```

Comment: it returns me : "[: 11: 0: unexpected operator
out ok
"